# Convert a type u16 number to a matrix (Vec<Vec<u8>> or array) of 4 x 4

Tags: strings, matrix, iterator, rust, vectors

I am a Rust newbie and I am not familiar with all the iterator options. This is what I have so far. How can I make this better or at least avoid collecting twice into a Vec?

```
let num: u16 = 0b0010001000100010; // input number
let bin = format!("{:016b}", num);

let parsed = bin
    .split("")
    .filter_map(|s| s.parse().ok())
    .collect::<Vec<u8>>();

let mat = parsed.chunks(4).collect::<Vec<_>>();

println!("{:?}", mat); 

// outputs [[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I'm going to do first is create an enum with only two values. This represents a binary value and is more memory-efficient than passing around a bunch of `u8`s. This way 16 `Bit`s can be represented as 16 actual bits in memory (though this isn't guaranteed).

```
/// a single bit
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
enum Bit {
    /// 1, high
    H1 = 1,
    /// 0, low
    L0 = 0,
}
use Bit::*; // allow us to just use `L0` and `H1` without the `Bit::` prefix
```

It is likely much faster to split a number into bits using numerical operators. There are a couple ways of doing it.

1. Iterating a mask

With this we increase our mask each time, building an array from it. The `15 - i` is there because we want the MSB at index 0.

```
/// convert a number to 16 bits by sliding a mask across it
fn into_bits_mask(num: u16) -> [Bit; 16] {
    let mut out = [L0; 16];

    for i in 0..16 {
        out[15 - i] = if num & (1u16 << i) > 0 {
            H1
        } else {
            L0
        };
    }

    out
}
```

2. Shifting the number with a static mask

This is essentially the same thing, but we shift the number instead of the mask.

```
/// convert a number to 16 bits by right-shifting it
fn into_bits_shift(num: u16) -> [Bit; 16] {
    let mut out = [L0; 16];

    for i in 0..16 {
        out[15 - i] = if (num >> i) & 1u16 > 0 {
            H1
        } else {
            L0
        };
    }

    out
}
```

We can then modify these to output an array of 4 nibbles.

```
/// convert a number to 4 nibbles by sliding a mask across it
fn into_nibbles_mask(num: u16) -> [[Bit; 4]; 4] {
    let mut out = [[L0; 4]; 4];

    for i in 0..16 {
        let mask = 1u16 << (15 - i);
        out[i / 4][i % 4] = if num & mask > 0 {
            H1
        } else {
            L0
        };
    }

    out
}

/// convert a number to 4 nibbles by right-shifting it
fn into_nibbles_shift(num: u16) -> [[Bit; 4]; 4] {
    let mut out = [[L0; 4]; 4];

    for i in 0..16 {
        out[i /4][i % 4] = if (num >> (15 - i)) & 1u16 > 0 {
            H1
        } else {
            L0
        };
    }

    out
}
```

There is room for more optimization here, of course.

Here's a working example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=b010e34728d554e995e0de4ddb4b1eed

EDIT: I was asked about using iterators, so here's my most iterator-function styled method

```
/// convert a number to 4 nibbles using iterator methods
fn into_nibbles_iter(num: u16) -> Vec<Vec<Bit>> {
    // split into nibbles
    [num >> 12, num >> 8, num >> 4, num]
        .iter()
        .map(|nibble| {
            // mask off each bit
            [nibble & 8, nibble & 4, nibble & 2, nibble & 1]
                .iter()
                // convert to Bits
                .map(|b| if b > &0 { H1 } else { L0 })
                .collect()
        })
        .collect()
}
```

And here's a new playground link demonstrating it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=5ecda81379c3cab749709f551109adfb

Comment: This is amazing @PitaJ and thanks for the working example. I am curious about doing it using iterators regardless of performance

Comment: @matharumanpreet00 I've added an iterator-styled method. Does that answer your question?